# increase php variable in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem and I do not know if the method I am using is correct. 
I want to decrease the variable $ pag -1 if a record is deleted. 
I do this because I have a pagination and affects which records are deleted, I must decrease that variable I use in the pagination. 
In this code I decreases though it has not eliminated any registration. 
How can I do to make me decrease the variable only if a record is deleted?
her code:

```
<?php $pag=20; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.delete').live("click",function() 
    {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var dataString = 'id='+ ID; 
      jConfirm('DELETE?',
      function(r) {
        if(r==true)
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "delete.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function(){               
              $("#stbody"+ID).animate({'backgroundColor':'#F2F2F2'},300);},
              success: function(html){
              $("#body"+ID).fadeOut(300,function(){$("#body"+ID).remove();});
              //div update
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $("#apDiv101").load('disminuye.php');
              }, 100);
          }
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>

<!--html delete-->
<a class="delete" href="#" id="<?php echo $id;?>" title="DELETE"></a>

<!--DIV update-->
<div id="apDiv101"><?php 
  include('disminuye.php'); 
?></div>
```

### file disminuye.php

```
<?php
$pag = $pag-1;
echo $pag;
?>
```

Comment: you need to use the variable send by jQuery: `$pag = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: Hum, I don't think `GET['id']` is the number of pages. And @user3462094 please indent your code.

Comment: Fair enough, it's the only data being sent to PHP. Otherwise @user3462094 you're going to need to store the current value in a session, or get it from a database. It won't persist across AJAX requests.

Comment: Yep, +1. But as you do an ajax call you can handle that server side, JS is inappropriate here.

Comment: And why there is two `$('.delete').live("click",function()`?

Comment: one my mistake Biduleohm :)
my pagination is through post, where you give click a button (see more) and the value $pag + $num is sent 
to top the $pag=0 and $num=20. 
But in the code I put them it's just an example of what I want to do. 
I want to decrease if a record is deleted, because if one eliminates, and give click on the button "see more" certain records does not appear, because he eats, records are walking. 
My sql LIMIT statement in LIMIT $pag, $num 
I hope you understand me, I do not speak much english.

Comment: I want to decrease the value of $pag if there is a removal.

Comment: I suggest you use cookies --- before the ajax call to delete do --- $.cookie("del", "1");  --- grab it in your PHP script -- $del = $_COOKIE["del"];  -- then check if its 1 and delete 1 from the pages. Set it back to 0 at the end of the PHP script ---  setcookie("del", "0");  ---- you will need a cookie js pluging to put in your html --- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Ok, no worries. Your comment isn't very clear but the solutions posted by scrowler and Tasos are both valid so use it ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions.
then tell them how I was.
All suggestions welcome